# Loading gif not waiting for iFrame to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a loading `.gif` to display until everything has loaded including an embedded `iframe`. However, currently the loading `gif` disappears once everything has loaded apart from the `iframe`. How can I get it to wait until the `iframe` has loaded too?

Currently using this:

```
<script>
  $(window).ready(function() {
    $('#loadinga').hide();
  });
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: try `$('iframe').load(() => .. )`

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe name="xyz"></iframe>

<script>
  var expectedLoadCount = 2; 

  function checkEverythingLoaded() {
    expectedLoadCount--;
    if (expectedLoadCount > 0) return
    $('#loadinga').hide();
  }

  $("#xyz").on("load", checkEverythingLoaded);
  $(window).ready(checkEverythingLoaded);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your iframe id is `iframeId`

then try with this-

```
<iframe id="iframeId" src="..."></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('iframeId').onload = function() {
$('#loadinga').hide();

  alert('iframe is loaded');
};
</script>
```